# When nesting clip, how to make new sequence same resolution as clip instead of original sequence?

Tags: premiere

The scenario is this: I have a standard HD resolution sequence, which I drop a 4k clip into. Later I decide I want to use Warp Stabilizer on that clip in the sequence, but I get an error message saying I need to nest the 4k clip in order to use stabilizer.  The easiest thing to do then is right click the clip and choose Nest...

The problem is that the newly created nest sequence uses the resolution of the original sequence, instead of matching itself to the 4k clip resolution. This means the Warp Stabilizer still won't work.

I can get a nested 4k sequence manually with a lot of steps, but is there a better way to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can automatically create a sequence from a clip by right-clicking on it in the project panel and selecting "New Sequence From Clip". This will create a sequence matching the resolution and framerate of the clip and put the clip in it. You can drop the newly created sequence in your original sequence like any other asset in the project panel.

Comment: That will do for now, although it requires a few extra clicks going to the right clip in the Project Panel and dragging the new sequence into place. Adobe really needs to make that "Nest..." button configurable.